# What is the pronunciation of "Aussie"?

Tags: pronunciation, proper-nouns

I know that Australians pronounce Aussie like *Oz-ee*.  However, how should Americans pronounce it?

I have, in the past, politely corrected Americans when I hear the typical "aw-see" ([\ä-sē\](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aussie)).  It seems to be pretty widely unknown that Australians say *Oz-ee*.

Then, I came across a website that *specifically* listed *Oz-ee* in the **wrong pronunciation** column (not even in the "alternate" column).  I emailed the author saying that I did not understand why this pronunciation was explicitly in the "wrong" column, and not at the very least in the alternate column.

This set the author off into a rant about how tiny dialects should not be indulged with setting the correct pronunciation for the rest of the English-speaking world.  However, amid all the ranting, the only objection I really received was that the *ss* shouldn't become a *z*.

So what's the answer?  Should English-speakers, no matter their dialect, use the pronunciation that the subject of the word itself uses?  Or was this author correct, that the generally-accepted North American usage of *aw-see* is categorically "correct" for general usage, and *Oz-ee* should be relegated to "tiny, insignificant, meaningless dialects"*?

**In other words, which is the correct pronunciation for North American speakers?** I guess this question has three possible answers:

1. The Australian pronunciation is correct.
2. Both are OK.
3. Americans should regard the Australian pronunciation as *wrong* for the North American accent/dialect.

---

<sup>* His words, not mine :)  I repeat it here to give a sense of the tone of the rant, not because I (even remotely) concur.</sup>

Comment: "tiny, insignificant, meaningless dialects" - like Aussie ?

Comment: @Renesis Interesting. I'd like to know how often you hear other Americans say _Aussie_? In retrospect, I feel that we simply use _Australian_ in almost all contexts unless we're trying to be amusing...

Comment: One can answer the question of what North American speakers do in general, though you already linked the dictionary entry which clearly shows both variations and where they are used.  Beyond that, you're just asking for people's opinions about how they *think* people *should* pronounce this word.  So the facts that answer the objective part of your question are already laid out, leaving this question as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, actually I am just asking what is correct, I haven't concluded that is subjective at all. The link is *one source* for common/accepted usages across the spoken English language. I really would like more than just opinion. That one can find arguments against answers to the question doesn't make the question itself argumentative (just look at Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Renesis: There is no governing body for the English language that says one pronunciation is right and others are wrong.  So, aside from sources for common/accepted usages, what would one base an objective answer on?  In other words, how can someone answer what North American and other English speakers "should" do, without just giving an opinion?  Indeed, the top-voted answer is an opinion.

Comment: If you were talking to me (an Australian) and pronounced it "aw-see", I would probably cringe a little. Your pronunciation should probably depend on your target audience - if you're using the term around some hoighty-toighty US scholar, go with "aw-see"

Comment: @Kosmonaut - well, I understand that *most* people could only give an opinion.  But, I was hoping that someone had more information about what would constitute a correct pronunciation.  After all, Stack Exchange shouldn't always just be for easy questions.

Comment: @Renesis: I asked you how it would even be *possible* to give more than an opinion.  Can you give an example of a hypothetical answer that would yield an objective answer to this question?

Comment: @Kosmonaut - answer here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/close-reconsideration-what-constitutes-subjective-and-argumentative

Answer (score 8):

"Aussie" first of all, is pronounced "Oz-ee" as you pointed out. That's how it's pronounced here in Australia.

It doesn't matter if it doesn't follow the rest of the pronunciation of the world. It's like our name, and our name is pronounced the way we pronounce it.

This is like when you ask someone his name, he will tell you how to pronounce it, even if it doesn't seem to follow English pronunciaton names. i.e. Boissevain is pronounced "Boh-se vah" (That's my friend's name).

Comment: It's also pronounced 'Ozzie' in England.

Comment: When you say "United States of America", I hope you pronounce the vowels the way we do here, or else you're doing it "wrong".  More to the point, this answer is almost completely your opinion — not backed up by the dictionary, and not backed up by facts (since when does every country pronounce every other country's name/nicknames the same?).

Comment: Lighten up. Have you ever used the name Calcutta, or Paris? Neither is correctly pronounced by the majority of the world. I agree the Australian accent shouldn't be considered insignificant with regard to our own words, but neither should it be considered the be all and end all. Pronouncing Paris correctly is jarring in English, and it makes sense to use our own pronunciation. Regardless, it's not a major issue.

Comment: Well, I used to think that Paris was pronounced Pari-s, but since I knew how to pronounce it, I've changed it to "Pari", and so should anyone who have learned that "Aussie" is pronounced "Ozzie"

Comment: In America, people from Oregon pronounces their state "Or-ah-gin," but the entire rest of the country pronounces it "Or-ah-gon."  Which is correct?

Comment: While I can see the points from all sides, foreign words, inflection, and vowels are really not adequate comparisons for a change in the pronuciation of a consonant.

Comment: @Renesis: Okay, so how about my point about "United States of America"?  That's a name for an English-speaking country.

Comment: @Kosmonaut By the way, is _America_ pronounced /əˈmɛrəkə/, or is it pronounced /əˈmɛrikə/ as in Italian?

Comment: @Kosmonaut earlier you said *"I hope you pronounce the vowels the way we do here"* -- I said "foreign words, inflection, and vowels"

Comment: @Renesis: Okay, rather than ask you why vowel pronunciation is not an adequate comparison for consonants (because I really don't get that), I will just give you another example, because this is just becoming silly at this point: "New York".  Do you pronounce the /ɹ/ "correctly"?

Comment: @Kosmonaut - Now I'm actually getting the argumentative part of this. I'm not even arguing with you. I even just repeated my prior message which you must have misread, yet for some reason you are now saying "this is becoming silly".  Consonants are different because *most* dialectal differences are in vowels.  Your "New York" example is a much better one.  Like I've said all along, I'm not the expert, and I'm not attempting to answer -- maybe now you know why I asked it!

Comment: @Renesis: It seems like you are not even trying to understand what people are saying, that's why it's becoming silly.

Comment: @Kosmonaut - what do you mean by that? What has given you that impression?  In fact, I had only made one comment and then repeated it when you said that.

Comment: @Renesis: I originally assumed you meant foreign [words, inflection, and vowels] — why would there be a "right" way to voice a consonant in a word but no "right" way to do vowels?  But that aside, even if you don't like an example with vowels, surely you can come up with your own example that uses consonants.  It seems like you are just trying to be argumentative at this point.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, just realize that I only made that one point. It was not my intention to be argumentative or even defend that point. It could be a poor reason, but I'm just searching for an explanation for why Aussie vs Ozzie doesn't feel like a difference in accent or dialect, which have been the topic of this comment thread.

Comment: This answer is silly. People from different regions pronounce words differently, regardless of how they're pronounced in the origin region. Sometimes they'll borrow the same pronunciation, and sometimes they don't. In AmE, for example, "Aussie" is typically pronounced with an "s" sound rather than a "z". That's correct—for American English. Aussie English pronunciation is *different*. Neither is "wrong". Trying to argue with or change this is like hoping the sun won't rise tomorrow. It's just how things work...

Answer (score 5):

A few things in Australia get shortened and pronounced with a "z" sound, with or without "z" spelling, mosquito = mossie, costume = cozzy, position = pozzzy. And it happens a lot to people's names, Barry = Bazza, Darrel = Dazza, Gary = Gazza, Karen = Kaz, etc, etc. Just seems to be a sound liked in Oz by Aussies.

Answer (score 2):

In the USA, we pronounce it with a soft s sound like snake rather than a z sound.

So pronounced just like it looks.  I guess we are just a little softer than our brothers down under.

Comment: And rounder. ;-)

Comment: Heh I go to the University of Arizona.  Definitely curvy, not so many round ones around here.  :)

Answer (score 2):

As a Pom living in Australia for the last 42 years, I can only echo what @Ham and Bacon said: the pronunciation is 'Oz-ee' here.

It seems to be responsible for a back-formation: Aussies come from Oz, of course. *We're not in Kansas, any more...*

Comment: +1 *We're not in Kansas, any more...*

Answer (score 2):

I've lived in California all my life, and I've been pronouncing it "Ozzie" since the late 80s or so.  Prior to that, I - and, I suspect, most Americans - had never heard an Australian pronounce the word; I don't recall that I said "Aussie" very often (if at all), but if I did,   it certainly wouldn't have crossed my mind to turn "ss" into "z".

But a funny thing happened in the 80s: the Aussies invaded America.  *Crocodile Dundee*, Olivia Newton-John, Foster's Lager, Men At Work, Midnight Oil... and a line of haircare products in purple bottles - called "Aussie" - that were advertised relentlessly on radio and television.  I may be a slow learner, but I only had to hear that **@%^&** kangaroo pronounce it twenty times or so before I got the message: it's pronounced with a zed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's both. People should use whatever they use. Look at words like adult, amen, missile, Pakistani...